# Qt5 with CMake not compiling .ui file when related source files are put into a library

Tags: cmake, qt5

I am trying to compile a Qt5 project with multiple subdirectories with CMake. Some of the Qt .ui file related code is compiled as library using `add_library` command. I found that the `ui_*.h` header file is not compiled with `uic` at all. But if I put .ui related sources files in `add_executable`, then the `ui_*.h` file is automatically generated. Here I provided a sample project that helps demonstrate this problem. The entire zipped project file can be accessed through https://www.dropbox.com/s/q2i9imexhjarsbf/qt5-cmake.zip?dl=0. The CMakeLists.txt file is shown below. I know there are other posts related to `ui_*.h` files not generated, but they don't seem to have a answer that can solve my problem.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.11)

project(helloworld)

# Find includes in the build directories
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

# Turn on automatic invocation of the MOC
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)


# Add a compiler flag
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall")

# Find the QtWidgets library
find_package(Qt5Widgets REQUIRED)

# Generate code from ui files
qt5_wrap_ui(UI_HEADERS mainwindow.ui)

# Generate rules for building source files from the resources
qt5_add_resources(QRCS resources.qrc)

add_library(window mainwindow.cpp)
target_link_libraries(window Qt5::Widgets)
# Tell CMake to create the helloworld executable
#add_executable(helloworld main.cpp mainwindow.cpp ${UI_HEADERS} ${QRCS})
add_executable(helloworld main.cpp ${UI_HEADERS})

# Add the Qt5 Widgets for linking
target_link_libraries(helloworld window Qt5::Widgets)
```

Comment: I found out the solution. the line `add_library(window mainwindow.cpp)` should be changed to `add_library(window mainwindow.cpp ${UI_HEADERS})`

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer and mark it as accepted to indicate the question is solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the solution. the line add_library(window mainwindow.cpp) should be changed to add_library(window mainwindow.cpp ${UI_HEADERS})